# Object to Array of objects conversion in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I need to convert object to array of object to work with angular2 *ngFor directive. i have got following json object.

```
Object {CountryID: 87944818, ISO2: "do", ISO3: "u", Name: "aliqua sit magna tempor"}
```

I need to convert that into array of object like this:

```
[Object]
     0: Object
       CountryID: 87944818
       ISO2: "do"
       ISO3: "u"
       Name: "aliqua sit magna tempor"
```

I have done some work around using Object.keys and map but could not acheive the exact output.
Have tried some thing like that:

```
let keys:any[] = [];
        for (let key in value) {
            console.log(key);
            keys.push({key: value[key]});
        }
        console.log(keys);
```

value is the object that need to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just have an array and push the object into it?

```
let myObj = {CountryID: 87944818, ISO2: "do", ISO3: "u", Name: "aliqua sit magna tempor"}
let myArr = [];
myArr.push(myObj);
console.log(myArr);
```

#### Edit:

Or you can just do:

```
myArr = [myObj]
```

Comment: Why not myArr=[myObj]

Comment: Yup. And No this is not destructuring. This is ES3

Comment: @CozyAzure Thanks, that was much simple. actually my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
keys.push({[key]: value[key]});
```

You dont want to set "key" but rather value of key.

Keys will be:

```
[
  {CountryID: 87944818},
  {ISO2: "do"},
  {ISO3: "u"},
  {Name: "aliqua sit magna tempor"},
]
```

I dont know why this should be useful...